# dynamically create and append element isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I know there's a ton of questions similar to it, but I couldn't figure it out after hours or reading. My code is:

```
var createTweet = function(tweet) {
  //Create elements

  var $profile = $('<img class="profile-photo" src="">');
  $profile.attr("src", tweet.profilePhotoURL);
  var $username = $('<div class="username"></div>');
  $username.text('@' + tweet.user);
  var $message = $('<div class="message"></div>');
  $message.text(tweet.message);
  $timeStamp = $('<div class="timestamp"></div>');
  var elapsedSecs = Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - tweet.created_at.getTime()) / 1000);
  if (elapsedSecs > 60) {
    var elapsedMins = Math.floor(elapsedSecs / 60)
    $timeStamp.text(elapsedMins + ' mins ago');
  } else {
    $timeStamp.text(elapsedSecs + ' secs ago');
  }
  $icons = $('<div class="icons"></div>');

  var $commentIcon = $('<img class="icon comment" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $retweetIcon = $('<img class="icon retweet" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $likeIcon = $('<img class="icon like" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $shareIcon = $('<img class="icon share" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');

  //Append to $icons

  $commentIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $retweetIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $likeIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $shareIcon.appendTo($icons);

  //Append to $tweet

  $profile.appendTo($tweet);
  $username.appendTo($tweet);
  $message.appendTo($tweet);
  $timeStamp.appendTo($tweet);
  $icons.appendTo($tweet);

};


var handleUpdateClick = function() {
  index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index > lastIndex) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
    createTweet(tweet);
    $tweet.prependTo($feed);
    index -= 1;
    lastIndex++;
  }
};

$("body").on("click", "button#update-feed", handleUpdateClick);
```

It's not showing up properly, and in the console the elements don't show up properly even though $tweet shows up.

What it looks like in the browser:

[image: What it looks like in the browser]

And this is the code that worked outside of the .on click:

```
      var index = streams.home.length - 1;
      var lastIndex = 0;
      while(index >= 0){
        var tweet = streams.home[index];
        var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
        createTweet(tweet);
        $tweet.prependTo($feed);
        index -= 1;
        lastIndex++;
      };
```

Comment: Can you specify what "properly" looks like?

Comment: There's no `$tweet` variable in `createTweet()`.

Comment: I added the pictures. I used the same code outside of the .on click, and the elements show that the message, username, etc are added as the child elements, and they show up in the window. I expected that using the same code, the same thing would happen except with the next randomly generated set of information

Comment: Please don't include code as links to images of code, especially with a link text of "enter image description here". Please copy and paste the text of the code here and format it appropriately.

Comment: The global variable `$tweet` must be referring to the DIV at the end where all the tweets are being appended.

Comment: Then how do I make it so that on the click of the button it will keep creating a new $tweet element w/ the proper child elements iterating through the collection of random information?As of now, it only creates the $tweet, but it has nothing inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`$tweet` is a local variable in `handleUpdateClick()`. You need to pass it as a parameter to `createTweet()`.

```
var createTweet = function(tweet, $tweet) {
  //Create elements

  var $profile = $('<img class="profile-photo" src="">');
  $profile.attr("src", tweet.profilePhotoURL);
  var $username = $('<div class="username"></div>');
  $username.text('@' + tweet.user);
  var $message = $('<div class="message"></div>');
  $message.text(tweet.message);
  $timeStamp = $('<div class="timestamp"></div>');
  var elapsedSecs = Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - tweet.created_at.getTime()) / 1000);
  if (elapsedSecs > 60) {
    var elapsedMins = Math.floor(elapsedSecs / 60)
    $timeStamp.text(elapsedMins + ' mins ago');
  } else {
    $timeStamp.text(elapsedSecs + ' secs ago');
  }
  $icons = $('<div class="icons"></div>');

  var $commentIcon = $('<img class="icon comment" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $retweetIcon = $('<img class="icon retweet" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $likeIcon = $('<img class="icon like" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');
  var $shareIcon = $('<img class="icon share" src="./assets/icons/placeholder.png">');

  //Append to $icons

  $commentIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $retweetIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $likeIcon.appendTo($icons);
  $shareIcon.appendTo($icons);

  //Append to $tweet

  $profile.appendTo($tweet);
  $username.appendTo($tweet);
  $message.appendTo($tweet);
  $timeStamp.appendTo($tweet);
  $icons.appendTo($tweet);

};


var handleUpdateClick = function() {
  index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index > lastIndex) {
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
    createTweet(tweet, $tweet);
    $tweet.prependTo($feed);
    index -= 1;
    lastIndex++;
  }
};

$("body").on("click", "button#update-feed", handleUpdateClick);
```

If you're not getting an error for the undefined variable, it must be because you also have a global variable named `$tweet`. But that's not what you're assigning in `handleUpdateClick`, so you're appending the new tweet to the wrong element.

Comment: I didn't get an error for the undefined variable before. I did try adding the $tweet as a parameter, but that didn't solve the issues. the

Comment: You don't show how `$feed` is set, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: var $feed = $('<div id="#feed"></div>'); was how I set it.